# Per server prefixs

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I was wondering how I would go about allowing every server my bot is connected to, to set their own prefix. I am using the async version of dpy with Commands ext. 
I would assume you would store the prefix's and server name in a .json file, but I don't know how you would write them or check the file for them.

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You can do this with dynamic command prefixes. Write a function or coroutine that takes a `Bot` and a `Message` and outputs the appropriate prefix for that message.  Assuming you had a JSON of server ids to prefixes:

```
{ 
  "1234": "!",
  "5678": "?"
}
```

You can load that json into a dictionary and then look up server ids in that dictionary.  Below I also include a default prefix, but you could also raise a `CommandError` or something for servers with no specific prefix.

```
from discord import commands
import json

with open("prefixes.json") as f:
    prefixes = json.load(f)
default_prefix = "!"

def prefix(bot, message):
    id = message.guild.id
    return prefixes.get(id, default_prefix)

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix)

...
```

Comment: Using that gives me this error:
`C:\Users\Tims Laptop>"C:\Users\Tim\Desktop\Nami Bot\Bot\Nami.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tims Laptop\Desktop\Nami Bot\Bot\Nami.py", line 16, in <module>
    prefixes = json.load("prefixes.json")
  File "C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 296, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x04480FF0>
`

Comment: My mistake. Try it with the change i just made

Comment: That works, thanks! How would I write the prefix, as I know how to write but if it needs to be before the bracket `}`, and if they change the servers prefix it needs to overwrite it. 
EDIT: When I change the servers prefix in the file I have to restart the bot for it to take effect?

Comment: also how would I set a default prefix for all servers?

Comment: Just as a note, message.server.id has been replaced with message.guild.id

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but for those others also looking for this you can use the `get_prefix` function.

*It's very similar to Patrick Haugh's version, but a little different maybe because of different discord library versions?*

```
prefixes = ['.','!','s.','k!']
ser_pref={'server id':['.',',']}
def get_prefix(bot, msg):
    if msg.guild.id in ser_pref:
        return commands.when_mentioned_or(*ser_pref['server id'])


    return commands.when_mentioned_or(*prefixes)(bot, msg)

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=get_prefix)
```

You can then later make commands to allow more custom server prefixes to other servers by adding their options to the dict