# Discord.py rewrite multi server data

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So I've been working with discord.py for a while now and recently switched over to discord.py-rewrite. I can't seem to find anything really about how to do this. But I would like to have like per guild data. For example if the bot is in `Server 1` and `Owner1` does `-prefix !!` it would add that to their prefixes but only in their guild. So it would not be a prefix in `Server2`. Any help would be great. I've been told I can do this with `JSON` files but can't find anything on it for what I want.

Comment: Here are some duplicates.  Even though it's for the async branch, none of the relevant parts were changed: [Per server prefix's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51915962/per-server-prefixs) [discord.py add to json file on server add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52612358/discord-py-add-to-json-file-on-server-add)

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out

Answer (score 1):

I am a discord bot maker myself and sometimes I have this issue.
I have created a workaround for this.

What you need is a dictionary instead of variables.
The key of the dictionary is the guild attributes and the value is the date for that guild.

Here is my snippet of code:

```
# Changing variables and setting them
#--------------------------------------------------------------

# Changing the values of a dictionary.
def guildvarchg(variable, guild, value): # Guild Variable Change
    for key in variable.keys(): # Do not change any of this.
        if key == guild:
            variable[key] = value

# To get a certain guild's variable, add [guild id] to the dictionary name.
# For example: variable[ctx.author.guild] # takes the data for that guild

# You are going to run into a first time setup issue. 
# To counter this, and for every new guild, add this if statement:

if ctx.author.guild not in variable: # only use this in a command definition
    variable[ctx.author.guild] = 'New value' # adds a new server to the data.
else:
    guildvarchg(variable, ctx.author.guild, new_value) # <<< overwrites the server data


#--------------------------------------------------------------
```

It is recommended that you create all variables [dictionaries] before running

```
variable{None:None} # Format after setting: variable{guild_id, data}
```