# Custom Prefix Discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, discord.py

I'm trying to find a way to create a command that can set a custom prefix for different servers for my bot. I'm using Cogs too if that helps in any way...

**Main File:**

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '/')

@client.command()
async def load(ctx, extension):
    client.load_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')

@client.command()
async def unload(ctx, extension):
    client.unload_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')

for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
      client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')


client.run('My Token')
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51915962/per-server-prefixs

Answer (score 0):

```py
async def get_prefix(bot, message):
    guild = message.guild
    # you can do something here with the guild obj, open a file and return something different per guild
    default_prefix, custom_prefix = '.', '>'
    return [default_prefix, custom_prefix]

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=get_prefix)
```

The functiol will be called everytime a command is processed.